# Creating folders in Jenkins with Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a problem with understanding job-dsl-plugin. I would like to create folders in my jenkins workspace but I don't know how to connect groovy script (and Object Oriented Programming) with dsl plugin.

```
class JenkinsDSL {
    def addFolder(def name) {
        println(name)
        //---GroovyDSL---
        folder(name) {
            displayName(name)
            description("${name} for project")
        }
        //---------------    
    }
}

def job = new JenkinsDSL()

job.addFolder("folder1")
job.addFolder("folder2")
```

Above script return the error:

```
javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptException: (script, line 5) No signature of method: JenkinsDSL.folder() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, JenkinsDSL$_addFolder_closure1) values: [folder1, JenkinsDSL$_addFolder_closure1@3fac6b47]
```

In configuration of Freestyle Project in Jenkins I tried to set the build step to groovy script and Process Job DSLs but I'm not sure which should be correct.

Answer (score 2):

It looks your task is to create a folder in a workspace using a freestyle project.
Do the following:
- name your freestyle project by the name of the folder, you would like to create.
- in the build step execute any valid shell command.
After you run the job - the folder with the the name of the project will be created in the workspace.

Comment: I understand but I need to create ca. 1000 folders and jobs inside of them. I will not do it with shell command

Comment: In case you don't want to put inside your shell script a loop for creating those folders and jobs - you can insert such loop inside your favorite language (e.g Groovy) program and call that program from a shell script.